# how to configure database connection with an properties file which is fetching from an remote server

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to fetch database connection properties file from an remote server.Then, I need to load that database properties file and run spring 3.0.5 API. As of now, i can download  properties file from remote server and store in an local directory.
If they is any better approach please let us know.

Answer (score 0):

With spring boot, I did something similar to this. The client is just a class that gets database config via HTTP call and return simple Connect DTO. You can replace DTO with File for your case. So it creates data source bean that spring will be able to use. If you are not using spring boot, you will need to pass this data source bean for your JPA provider if you are using it or just use it with a plain JDBC approach.

```
@Configuration
public class DynamicDataSourceConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(Client client) {
        Optional<Connection> databaseConfig = client.getDatabaseConfig();

        Connection connection = databaseConfig.orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new);

        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .url(connection.getUri())
                .username(connection.getUser())
                .password(connection.getPassword())
                .build();
    }
```

}